# How is the normalized power required for unipolar NRZ twice that of polar NRZ?

Tags: digital-communications, sampling, modulation, polar

[image]

So, the normalized power for unipolar NRZ scheme is $\frac{1}{2}V^2$. According to my book, the normalized power required for polar NRZ is half that of unipolar NRZ. So, the power should be $\frac{V^2}{4}$.

[image]

However, the normalized power for polar NRZ seems to me to be $\frac{1}{2}V^2+\frac{1}{2}(-V)^2=V^2$. Can someone please explain this contradiction?

Diagrams from Data Communications and Networking, Behrouz A. Forouzan, p. 101-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the levels of the polar signal were $\pm V$ you would be right, but then it wouldn't be a fair comparison with the unipolar signal with levels $+V$ and zero. A fair comparison would be to have the same *difference* between the two levels. So we look at a polar signal with levels $\pm V/2$, which has a power of $V^2/4$.

Comment: ok so if for unipolar nrz the levels are 5V and 0V, then for polar nrz we have to use +2.5V and -2.5V?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic: Yes, for the comparison to be fair.